# cast from float32 to int in Go

Tags: casting, go, rounding

I have tried several ways to cast a float to an int, what I want is to truncate a float so I only get the integer part.
I'm using

```
x := float32(3.1)
y,_ := strconv.Atoi((strconv.Ftoa32(x,'f',0))) //y becomes 3
```

But if x is 3.9, y will become 4 because this function will round the float32 instead of truncating.
Is there a way of truncating instead of rounding? and if so, is it possible to do it without involving strings? (like casting a float to int in C)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just use `int()`:

```
x := float32(3.1)
fmt.Println(int(x))
```

Which produces `3` as needed, without having to use string conversions or the like.

Comment: Looking back after years, here is why it was confusing - `int(3.2)` fails because the argument is a constant, additionally I was confused around type casting vs type asserting. As a Go newbie this was hard to understand.